# I have an issue using scene builder with intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, graphics, scenebuilder

Everything is working fine in scene builder and i run it from my main method in intellij .
But when i resize a fontawesomeIcon in the scene builder , this give me an error and doesnt run.
I tried looking for a specific module but i didnt find solution by myself.
Is there anyone having this kind of issues?

Comment: What is the specific error that you get?

Comment: at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:196)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:190)
 at de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphIcon.convert(GlyphIcon.java:248)
 at de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphIcon.setSize(GlyphIcon.java:144)
 ... 34 more
Exception running application sample.Main